# Checking if an element is present in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor test that expects a certain panel to be NOT PRESENT after login. My code is below, but every time it is executed, protractor hangs and then fails later on.

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

---

```
it('The team overlay page should not be present when another user logs in.', function() {

 loginPage.login(user.username, user.password);
 expect(element(by.css('div.panel#myPanel')).isPresent()).toBe(false);

});
```

I also tried using .count() but it also does the same thing. Same error as above.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('div.panel#myPanel')).count()).toBe(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try waiting for the element by allowing the browser to fully load with some of the following:

`browser.driver.sleep(time in milliseconds)`

`browser.waitForAngular()`

You could increase the timeout interval:

`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000`

**Otherwise**:

Make sure your locator via css is working correctly (i.e, test it when the panel should be present), and make sure the webpage you are trying to access supports Angular. My bet is there is something incorrect with the format of your locator, as I don't see what else could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I did test it when it should be present and it didnt have any problems. :) I'll try your solution first.